# ¿Es posible generar un reporte de los archivos excel que se han generado en un dia?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, apache-poi

Quisiera saber si es posible generar un reporte con una lista de los archivos excel que se han generado en un día, tengo un sistema que genera archivos excel, pero quería agregar una funcionalidad que me diga cuantos archivos excel se han generado en el día, de antemano muchas gracias.

Busco que se pueda agregar el reporte del archivo sin necesidad de guardarlo en una base de datos, algo así como consultar los archivos guardados en una carpeta en especifico.

Comment: ¿Y por qué no sería posible? Tienes muchas formas de hacerlo, llevando el conteo diario en algún tipo de variable o registro cada vez que generas un reporte o bien simplemente buscando los archivos cuya fecha de creación coincida con el día especificado. La pregunta es demasiado amplia.

Comment: Así es, como ya te dijeron, podrías crear una especie de "historial" en una tabla y almacenar ahí los datos que te interesen cada que se presione el botón de crear reporte.